# Update a reactive value in a loop for

Tags: r, shiny

I have a reactive *val* variable that needs to update a *progress circle widget* from package *shinybusy*. I have a function *f1* which takes the reactive variable as an argument. The function *f1* has a for loop and on each iteration I would like to update val.

I would like to know how to update a reactiveVal val inside the loop.

```r
library(shiny); library(shinyBS); library(shinybusy)

f1 <- function(val){
    for(i in 1:3){
        val(i); cat(paste0(i, "/", 3), "\r"); Sys.sleep(1)
    }
}

ui <- fluidPage(titlePanel(""), sidebarLayout( sidebarPanel(), mainPanel(
    actionButton("show_modal", "Modal")
)))

# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    val <- reactiveVal(0)

    observeEvent(input$show_modal,{
        showModal(modalDialog(
            title = "Modal", "Something",
            shinybusy::progress_circle(value = 0, color = "#112446", shiny_id = "circle"), easyClose = TRUE, footer = modalButton("Close") ))
        f1(val)
    })
    observe({ update_progress("circle", val()/3) })
}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

```r
library(shiny); library(shinybusy); library(ipc); library(doParallel); library(foreach); library(future); library(promises); plan(multisession);

f1 <- function(queue){
    print("===== f1 =====")
    cores <- detectCores() - 1; 
    cl <- makeCluster(cores); 
    registerDoParallel(cl)
    on.exit({
        stopCluster(cl)
        stopImplicitCluster()
    }, add = TRUE)
    df <- data.frame("i" = numeric(), "val" = numeric())
    future({
        for(i in 1:3){
            queue$producer$fireAssignReactive("Value", i)
            cat(paste0(i, "/", 3), "\r")
            df_ <- foreach(j = 1:5, 
                            .combine = "rbind") %dopar% {
                return(data.frame("id" = (i-1) * 5 + j, 
                                  "val" = j*i))
            }
            Sys.sleep(1)
            df <- rbind(df, df_)
        }
    }) #%>..>% df
    #return(df)
}

server <- function(input, output) {
    Value <- reactiveVal(0)
    queue <- shinyQueue()
    queue$consumer$start(100)
    observeEvent(input$show_modal,{
        showModal( modalDialog( ... ) )
        f1(queue)
    })
    ...
}
```

Comment: Cramming multiple statements on one line really makes this code less readable.

Answer (score 1):

With the packages **future** and **ipc**:

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinybusy)
library(ipc)
library(future)
library(promises)
plan(multisession)

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""), 
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(), 
    mainPanel(
      actionButton("show_modal", "Modal")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  Value <- reactiveVal(NULL)
  
  queue <- shinyQueue()
  queue$consumer$start(100) # Execute signals every 100 milliseconds
  
  observeEvent(input$show_modal,{
    
    showModal(modalDialog(
      title = "Modal", "Something",
      progress_circle(value = 0, color = "#112446", shiny_id = "circle"), 
      actionButton("x", "X"),
      easyClose = TRUE, 
      footer = modalButton("Close")
    ))
    
    future({
      for(i in 1:5) {
        Sys.sleep(2)
        queue$producer$fireAssignReactive("Value", i/5)
      }
    })
    
    NULL
  })
  
  observeEvent(Value(), {
    update_progress("circle", Value(), session = session)
  })

}

# Run the application
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hello, thank for your help. In my concrete case I use the doparallel and foreach packages in the f1 function to carry out the parallelization. Parallelization is not done inside the future function, I guess it's because I'm using plan(multisession) . How can I redo the code to use only the future package? (I edited my post). And how can I get the df result?

Comment: I found some leads: https://r-dev-perf.borishejblum.science/parall%C3%A9lisation-du-code-r.html (french article). It's use *future.apply* package